# Não identifico o erro - |35|error: 'd' undeclared (first use in this function)|

Tags: c, c++, variáveis, declaração-de-variável

Estou programando em C/C++ e deu um erro que não consigo identificá-lo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//Função Principal do Programa
 int main() {

      //Definindo variáveis
      int a = 5, b = 10, c = 15;

      //Maior
      if(a > 2){
         printf("\n %d Eh maior que 2\n", a);
      }

      //Maior ou Igual
      if(c >= b){
        printf("\n %d Eh maior ou igual a %d\n", c, b);
      }

      //Menor
      if(a < 10){
        printf("\n %d Eh menor que 10\n", a);
      }

     //Menor ou Igual
     if(a <= 10){
        printf("\n %d eh menor ou igual a 10\n", a);
     }

     //Diferente
      if(c != 10){
         printf("\n %d nao eh 10\n", c);
     }
      if(d != 'a'){
            printf("\n %c nao eh a", d);
     }

     //Pausa o Programa após executar
     system("pause");

}
```

Comment: Não que mude para este caso, mas precisa decidir se está programando em C ou C++, não dá para fazer em ambos.

Comment: Realmente, mas estou fazendo o curso de fundamentos de c e c++ então como sou iniciante não sei o certo se estou programando em c ou c++ (creio que c++), compreendo sua resposta, a cada dia que passa meus conhecimentos aumentam gradativamente, preferia que tivesse uma lista de "comandos" para saber corretamente declarar uma variável ou algo do tipo kkkk.   Mas obrigado pela atenção e sua resposta me ajudou muito.

Comment: Deveria ser a primeira coisa que o curso fala. Alias se o curso fala que é amos, o curso já tem problemas. Não tem uma linha de C++ nesse código, embora compile no compilador C++.

Comment: Verdade, concordo com cada palavra dita acima, e pesquisando listas de comandos percebi isso mesmo a linguagem usada é C. Agora em relação a instituição, não é das melhores mas eu faço Análise e desenvolvimento de sistemas e vou ter programação esse semestre, acontece é que já quis adiantar algumas coisas, só não sei se encontrei a melhor forma. A e além de "adiantar" eu vou adicionando conhecimentos ao meu currículo pois estou precisando trabalhar. Valeu por comentar cara.

Comment: Adicionar conhecimento não é um bom caminho, é melhor aprender e isto se faz de forma estruturada, com informações corretas, em ordem, com base anterior. Pode perguntar o que quiser aqui pra ir aprendendo, desde que seja pontual.

Comment: Obrigado, vi o seu perfil e você ministra cursos?

Comment: Não, mas estou pensando no assunto, o problema é que eu acho que a maioria das pessoas não gostariam dos meus cursos, as pessoas gostam dos cursos "me engana que eu gosto", eu faria algo bem puxado, que vai a fundo, que ensina mesmo, que manda o cara ir além, que mostra que é necessário questionar e não apenas absorver, as pessoas não gostam muito disso. Mas adivinha quem gosta bastante? O mercado de trabalho. Mas quem toma decisão sobre que curso fazer é a pessoa, mercado não tem consciência. De qualquer me adiciona em alguma rede, quem sabe saia alguma coisa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como a própria mensagem já indica, falta declarar a variável `d`. Está usando ela no último `if` sem que ela exista. Uma solução seria:

```
int a = 5, b = 10, c = 15
char d = 'a';
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Char/Declaration.c).

Comment: Nossa, obrigado cara mas na verdade tinha esquecido do  char d = 'x';                                                       não sei dizer minunciosamente para que serve mas era isso, mas se não fosse você não teria chegado a essa conclusão. Obrigado.

Comment: @dzarm é, eu nem me atentei que o último era diferente, corrigi agora.